# Easiest implementation of Graph in cpp

Tags: c++, vector, graph

Currently I am learning `graph` implementation. I found 2 implementation namely `matrix` and `adjacency list` using `vector` in cpp. But the problems I face are following

#### With matrix

- Passing to function is hard
- Adding new nodes is not possible
- memory inefficient

#### Vector implementation of adjacency list

```cpp
// Code taken from geeksforgeeks
vector<int> adj[V]; 

// adding edge from u to v
adj[u].push_back(v);
```

- adding new node is not possible
- and also passing to function is hard

So I want a solution in `cpp` which can solve above 2 problems.

Comment: Vector of vectors? And what do you mean "passing to function is hard"? What problem do you have passing your array `adj` to a function? As all arrays, it easily decays to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: If you don't want fixed-size containers (C-array/`std::array`), replace them by dynamic containers (`std::vector`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I think OP talked about "ugly" syntax to pass C-array by reference.

Comment: I think `pointer` is so hard topic for me. I am strictly following `social distancing` with it. And thanks @Someprogrammerdude and @PSKP for introducing me `vector of vectors`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have efficient and easiest implementation of `graph` in `cpp`. It solves all problems you mentioned above. It is called as `vector in vector`.

```cpp
// Suppose at start we have
// number of nodes
int nodes = 5;

// number of edges
int edges = 4;

// define graph
vector<vector<int>> graph(nodes, vector<int>());

int u, v; // edge from u -> v
for(int i=0;i<edges;i++){
    cin >> u >> v;
    graph[u].push_back(v);
}

// suppose we want to add node
graph.push_back(vector<int>());

// print graph content
int index = 0;
for(auto x : graph){
    cout << index << "-> ";
    for(auto y: x){
        cout << y << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    index ++;
}
```

#### Input to above code

```sh
5 4
0 1
0 2
2 1
2 3
```

#### Output

```sh
0-> 1 2 
1-> 
2-> 1 3 
3-> 
4-> 
5-> // new node
```

#### Advantages

- Can add node at run time
- memory efficient
- you can pass to function easily like normal vector
- you can find nodes in another function without passing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no mean efficient implementation, but a perhaps a set of pairs is what you are looking for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

template<class T>
class graph
{
public:
    std::set<std::pair<T, T>> storage;

    /* true item added, false otherwise */
    bool add_edge(T v1, T v2)
    {
        auto ret = storage.insert(std::make_pair(v1, v2));
        return ret.second;
    }

    /* return value: edges deleted */
    int delete_edge(T v1, T v2)
    {
        return storage.erase(std::make_pair(v1, v2));
    }

    void print_graph()
    {
        std::for_each(storage.begin(), storage.end(),
        [](std::pair<T, T> const& p) {
            std::cout << p.first << "--> " << p.second << std::endl;
        });
    }
};
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "graph.h"

int main()
{
    graph<int> g;
    g.add_edge(5, 4);
    g.add_edge(5, 4);
    g.add_edge(6, 2);
    g.print_graph();
    g.delete_edge(5, 4);
    g.print_graph();
    return 0;
}
```

**Compile command**

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp
```

**Output**

```
5 --> 4
6 --> 2
/* Deleted 5 --> 4 */
6 --> 2
```